# aligning output of ofstream

Tags: c++, iostream, fstream

I wish to output data from my program to a text file. Here is a working example showing how I do it currently, where I also include the date/time (I am running Windows):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

char dateStr [9];
char timeStr [9];

_strdate(dateStr);
_strtime(timeStr);

ofstream output("info.txt", ios::out);
output << "Start time part 1 " << "\t" << timeStr << " on " << dateStr << "\n";
output << "Start time part 1000000 " << "\t" << timeStr << " on " << dateStr << "\n";
output.close();


return 0;
}
```

However the output of "info.txt" is not very readable to me as a user, since the time- and date stamp at the ends are not aligned. Here is the output:

```
Start time part 1   15:55:43 on 10/23/12
Start time part 1000000     15:55:43 on 10/23/12
```

My question is, is there a way to align the latter part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [`<iomanip>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) header provides the `setw` manipulator, letting you set the width of each field that you output to an `ostream`. Using `setw` manipulator for each row instead of tab characters would provide tighter control over the output:

```
output << setw(25) << "Start time part 1 " << timeStr << " on " << dateStr << endl;
output << setw(25) << "Start time part 1000000 " << timeStr << " on " << dateStr << endl;
```

To align strings on the left, add `left` manipulator:

```
output << left << setw(25) << "Start time part 1 " << timeStr << " on " << dateStr << endl;
output << left << setw(25) << "Start time part 1000000 " << timeStr << " on " << dateStr << endl;
```

Comment: Just a note: while `std::setw` applies only to the *next* insertion, `std::left` permanently modifies the stream. If it's a global stream, like `std::cout`, a well-behaved method should save/restore [`output.flags()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) so your particular formatting preferences don't cause strange results elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 3):

```
int max_align = 10;
output << "Start time part 1 " << "\t" << timeStr 
<< std::string(max_align-timeStr.size(), " ") << " on " << dateStr << "\n";
```